# Ionic Icon and Splash screen not showing

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic3

I am using Ionic3. I am trying to create a custom icon and splash screen for my app.  I created an `icon.png` (432x193) and `splash.png` (6135x2733) in the `resources` folder.

I then run:

```
ionic cordova resources
✔ Collecting resource configuration and source images - done!
✔ Uploading source images to prepare for transformations - done!
✔ Generating platform resources: 38 / 38 complete - done!
✔ Modifying config.xml to add new image resources - done!
```

If I check `resources/android/icon`:

[image]

and `resources/android/splash`:

[image]

I can see the new images have been generated (I have `<preference name="orientation" value="portrait"/>`, so I think that's why only portrait images are generated, landscape has the default ionic ones).

I also check:

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.thewhozoo912107" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>theWhoZoo</name>
    <description>An awesome Ionic/Cordova app.</description>
    <author email="admin@thewhozoo.com" href="http://thewhozoo.com/">theWhoZoo Team</author>
    <content src="index.html"/>
    <access origin="*"/>
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
    <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="*"/>
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*"/>
        <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
        <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
        <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>
        <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
        <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
        <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
        <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
        <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
        <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
        <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
        <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
        <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*"/>
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" height="57"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" height="80"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" height="120"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" height="100"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" height="180"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" height="152"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" height="167"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" height="58"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" height="87"/>
        <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="1136"/>
        <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" height="1334"/>
        <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" height="2208"/>
        <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" height="2048"/>
        <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" height="2732"/>
        <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" height="1024"/>
        <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="960"/>
        <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" height="480"/>
    </platform>
    <allow-navigation href="*"/>
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true"/>
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300"/>
    <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000"/>
    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait"/>
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>
    <feature name="StatusBar">
        <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar"/>
    </feature>
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="~2.2.1"/>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.1"/>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="1.0.5"/>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.2.1"/>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="1.1.4"/>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~4.0.1"/>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebook4" spec="~1.7.4">
        <variable name="APP_ID" value="XXXXXXXXXX"/>
        <variable name="APP_NAME" value="theWhoZoo"/>
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-googleplus" spec="~5.1.1">
        <variable name="REVERSED_CLIENT_ID" value="com.googleusercontent.apps.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-crop" spec="~0.3.1"/>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-app-version" spec="~0.1.9"/>
</widget>
```

I then run:

```
ionic cordova build android
```

to build an `apk` file. When I install this `apk` on my Android device, the icon and splash screen is still the same default Cordova image:

[image]

If anyone can help, I would appreciate it.

More info:

```
global packages:

    @ionic/cli-utils : 1.3.0
    Cordova CLI      : 6.4.0 
    Ionic CLI        : 3.3.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.0
    @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.3.0
    @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.0
    Cordova Platforms               : android 6.0.0 ios 4.3.1
    Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.2.1

System:

    Node       : v7.10.0
    OS         : macOS Sierra
    Xcode      : Xcode 8.3.2 Build version 8E2002 
    ios-deploy : not installed
    ios-sim    : not installed
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there was a bug in an old version of Cordova. I did some reading, and the following resolved the issue:

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
ionic cordova platform add android@latest
ionic cordova resources
ionic cordova build android
```

You may also need to:

```
npm install -g cordova@latest
```

However, this only seems to have partially fixed the issue. The icon is now my custom icon, but the splash screen is just white.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to apps res directory:

> C:\Users\You\YourApk\platforms\android\res

2. Open all the folders one by one and replace the icon/image of cordova app icon by your Apps icon with the same size.

> ```
> - C:\Users\You\YourApk\platforms\android\res\drawable
> - C:\Users\You\YourApk\platforms\android\res\drawable-hdpi
> - C:\Users\You\YourApk\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-hdpi
> - C:\Users\You\YourApk\platforms\android\res\drawable-ldpi
> - C:\Users\You\YourApk\platforms\android\res\drawable-mdpi
> - C:\Users\You\YourApk\platforms\android\res\drawable-xhdpi
> ```

1. Then build your Application

If this is not enought, [some blog with extras](https://codereviewvideos.com/blog/fixing-ionic-icon-and-splashscreen-being-stuck-as-default/)

If standard method doesn´t work I will post the guide of that blog into this answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your issue go inside to resource folder of your project Then go to Android  or ios Folder (Its depend on your platforms)And Delete Icon and Splash Folder.
Then come back to resource folder and paste the splash and icon images in resources folder.
And rename them for Splash->splash.png , and for icon->icon.png.

Then

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
```

Then

```
ionic cordova platform add android
```

Then

```
ionic cordova resources
```

Finally , Ready To build and hence it will be success.

```
ionic cordova build android
```

Comment: "ionic cordova platform rm android" works fine, it removes the package from package.json, but then "ionic cordova platform add android" just says platform already exists and it doesn't make any changes back into package.json and I am using ionic 5.4.

Comment: I think your system does not allows to delete platform folder, So delete the platform folder manually or run cmd prompt as administrator then try I hope it will work....